# Track email from Gmail client with Mandrill

Tags: api, email, mandrill

My company just recently signed up to start using Mandrill and I have been put in charge of trying to get it set up, however I'm running into an issue. Ideally we'd like to use the ability to see if e-mails have been opened on an individual bases by tracking through the Mandrill Dashboard, but we are using Gmail as our e-mail client and sending sales messages, follow up, etc. via Gmail.

From what I've read Mandrill tracks the open rate, click rate and other stats by placing a small invisible image in the email, and if its downloaded it tracks it.

Is there a way to place that small, invsible image into my Gmail outgoing message and have it report to my Mandrill?

If not are there alternatives ways to still send from Gmail but track the statistics in my Mandrill dashboard? Are there other services that are better.

I know that I can open the Mandrill App and send from there, but it doesn't seem to use the templates very well. Is there a way to use the templates from inside the Mandrill App?

Thanks!

Comment: As I'd imagine you discovered, Mandrill's SMTP lands in the "updates" tab of Gmail every single time without fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Gmail doesn't allow you to specify an alternate sending server for emails being sent from a domain that they host or gmail.com because part of the service they provide includes actually sending the mail from their servers. There are some options with Google Apps for your domain, but they're fairly limited and don't appear to be compatible for the settings you'd need for sending through Mandrill.  Similarly, the service that Mandrill provides is designed to include actually sending the mail through our servers, so embedding the Mandrill tracking image in an email not sent through Mandrill wouldn't be possible.

You have a few different options. If you're intent on using Gmail's web interface, you may want to look in to Google Addons or extensions that allow you to get tracking information about your emails.

If you definitely want to use Mandrill, and take advantage of the variety of options that we offer, you can use a desktop email program, like Thunderbird or Apple Mail, and configure it to send through Mandrill. From there, you can either set custom headers (see our [blog post here](http://blog.mandrill.com/adding-custom-smtp-headers.html) for some information on doing that with Thunderbird and Apple Mail or you could use a [Rule](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/22087471-Rules-Engine) to automatically apply a template to mail you send that meets certain criteria such as coming from a specific sender or including certain information in the subject line.

Feel free to reach out to support, too, if you have more specific questions about your account. Easiest would be to use the Support button in your account so we can get more information and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you Kaitlin, this answered my question perfectly. I did reach out to support a couple of days ago now and haven't heard back, so I really appreciate your reply. This is exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mandrill through your gmail interface but it does require you to put in a different send (email) address. This can be done in the "Accounts" section of your gmail settings. Just add a send address then choose "Send emails through your SMTP server" and use the settings in your Mandrill dashboard.

Once you have added a new send email address the gmail interface gives you a drop down labelled "from" in the compose window under the "to" line. As long as you use the email you set up with the Mandrill SMTP all email that you send will automatically have any tracking code/images added and appear in the Mandrill dashboard.